# SQLite Database not working correctly

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm trying to save some data in an SQLite database in my iOS app. I'm doing this with the method below:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@', null, %d)", categoryName, @"test", @"test", 33];

NSLog(@"Query is: %@", query);

[[AFSQLManager sharedManager]performQuery:query withBlock:^(NSArray *row, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

    if (!error) {

        if (!finished) {
            NSLog(@"No success");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Succeeded");
        }
     } else {

         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:error.description delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];
     }
}];
```

And this is the method for opening the database, which is executed in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[AFSQLManager sharedManager]openLocalDatabaseWithName:@"test.sqlite" andStatusBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:error.description delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}];
```

As you can see, I'm using AFSQLManager for executing the queries (you can find it here https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFSQLManager). The method above logs 'succeeded', but when I pull some data from the database, I get no results. My best guess is that it's a problem with the `SQLite` database....any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside, you should never build your SQL with `stringWithFormat`. You should be using `?` placeholders in your SQL and bind values to those placeholders. I suspect that `AFSQLManager` might not be capable of that, so you might consider using a library like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which offers that capability.

Comment: Nine times out of ten your symptoms are due to not actually having the data base file located where it should be or where you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class you reference has a fairly fundamental problem in its opening routine, namely that it opens the database from the bundle:

```
-(void)openLocalDatabaseWithName:(NSString *)name andStatusBlock:(statusBlock)status {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[[name lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[name pathExtension]];

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        status(NO, nil);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Database opened properly");
        status(YES, nil);
    }
}
```

The bundle is read-only. Thus, any attempts to update data in that database will fail.

You have to copy the database to (or create data in) the Documents folder (or cache or temporary folder or whatever) before trying to open it if you want to update it.

Comment: Allright, that makes sense. This might be a bit too off-topic, but do you know of a better class then?